# not find Permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

can't find permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and not find Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS
android studio
android studio version is 2020.3.1
gradle version 4.1.3
compilerVersion 30
targetVersion 30

Answer (score 0):

Call this method before taking any file from storage

```
 

    private fun requestPermission() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
                    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                    intent.data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", requireContext().packageName))
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    val intent = Intent()
                    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000)
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    requireActivity(),
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    1000                )
            }
        }
```

Then in onActivityResult you can check request code if it is 1000 then get Uri from data intent

Answer (score 0):

**Declare the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```